# Table caption element is causing page to break when printing

Tags: html, css, html-table, caption

Consider the following table:

```
<table>
<caption>The caption</caption>
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody>...</tbody>
<tfoot>...</tfoot>
</table>
```

The table renders right when displaying on screen, but when printing it breaks the table for a new page. When I delete the caption element or display:none, the table renders right on printing.

Any help?

Comment: Are there a page-break properties assigned in CSS for this element? Example, "page-break-before" or "page-break-after"?

Comment: No, no page break properties assigned.

Answer (score 0):

According to W3C:

> The table  elements, table, tr, td, th, and caption, should have their standard meaning and display treatments: table, table-row, table-cell,  and table-caption.

From my understanding this means

```
caption { display: table-caption; }
```

EDIT: I found a more accurate style:

```
TABLE         { display: table }
TR            { display: table-row }
THEAD         { display: table-header-group }
TBODY         { display: table-row-group }
TFOOT         { display: table-footer-group }
COL           { display: table-column }
COLGROUP      { display: table-column-group }
TD, TH        { display: table-cell }
CAPTION       { display: table-caption }
```

Please tell me if this works for you.

For more detailed information about the topic, visit [THIS PAGE](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/)

Comment: Nope, did not work. Those display settings are the default. And I did not change any display setting of the table and its children elements. But thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you give a link to the page if it is live?

Comment: Unfortunately it's an intranet page. I'll try to get a more accurate code and post it here.